# Bound surface limits to a function

Tags: plotting, regions

Consider the following plot of two surfaces

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], x^3 + y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: plot]

How can I produce a plot where I limit the the surface plot of $\sin(x y)$, to be shown only when its values are above $x^3+y$, or any other given function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### ConditionalExpression

```
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], Sin[x y] > x^3 + y], 
  {x, -1,  1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

To show both functions

```
Plot3D[{ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], Sin[x y] > x^3 + y], x^3 + y }, 
  {x, -1,  1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Mesh -> None, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.7]]
```

[image]

#### MeshFunctions, MeshShading

```
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Sin[# #2] - #^3 - #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {None, Automatic}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

#### ImplicitRegion

```
ir = DiscretizeRegion @ ImplicitRegion[Sin[x y] > x^3 + y, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}];

Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, y} ∈ ir, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can utilize the option `RegionFunction` for that:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], x^3 + y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Mesh -> None,
 RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] Sin[x y] > (x^3 + y))
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Equivalently: `reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Sin[x y] > (x^3 + y), {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]]; Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, y} ∈ reg]`